# First hook to use current page post id

Tags: posts, hooks

I'm trying to find the first hook that will pass the current post ID, as I would like to update the current post (by getting its ID) and the variables submitted to that page.

This is the code I'm using:

```
class my_class {

    public function __construct(){

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'my_method' ) );
    }

    public function my_method( $atts ){

        // do my stuff with current page id here.
        // even just: echo post id and die();.

    }
}
```

Any hook, action or filter, and which one to use and why.

Comment: Could you elaborate which context you want to do this in? A front page load of singular post?

Comment: If you need to update the page before the main query fires and returns the page object, you will manually need to parse the URL (*probably on `init`*) and get the page ID from `get_page_by_title()` or `get_page_by_path()`. Otherwise, `wp` would be earliest hook to get the page ID

Answer (score 5):

Answer by @Pieter Goosen :

> If you need to update the page before the main query fires and returns
> the page object, you will manually need to parse the URL (probably on
> init) and get the page ID from get_page_by_title() or
> get_page_by_path().
>
> Otherwise, 'wp' would be earliest hook to get the page ID, for example:

```
function my_early_id() {
    $post = get_post();
    echo $post->ID;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_early_id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`the_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post) (see [action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request).). That is the first hook within the loop.

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not what OP was asking for...